# Representation of a unitary in terms of a self-adjoint operator (2)

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, c-star-algebras

If $A$ is a $C^\ast$-algebra and $u\in A$ is unitary and $\tau : \Omega (A) \to \mathbb C$ is the evaluation map why is $|\tau_u(\tau)|=|\tau(u)|=1 $ for all characters $\tau \in \Omega(A)$?

This seems to be used in the proof here:

Claim: Let $A$ be a $C^\ast$-algebra and $u$ be unitary. If $\sigma (u) \neq \mathbf T$ then there exists $a \in A$ self-adjoint s.t. $u=e^{ia}$.

Proof: We may assume that $-1 \notin \sigma (u)$ and that $A$ is commutative. Let $\varphi : A \to C_0 (\Omega (A))$ be the Gelfand representation and let $f = \varphi (u)$ and $\ln : \mathbb C \setminus (-\infty , 0]\to \mathbb C$ the principal branch of the logarithm. Then $g = \ln \circ f$ is a well-defined element of $C_0 (\Omega)$.

Since $|f(\omega)|=1$ for all $\omega \in \Omega$....

Why is $|f(\omega)|=1$?

Comment: (It is clear to me that $|f(\omega)|\le 1$ since $\|\omega\|=1$ but equality I don't see)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have, 
$$
|f(\omega)|^2=|\omega(u)|^2=\overline{\omega(u)}\omega(u)=\omega(u^*)\omega(u)=\omega(u^*u)=\omega(I)=1.
$$